# Uploading image to s3 bucket usket using aws sdk php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to move a file from my php code to s3 bucket using this code:

```
  $bucket = "bucket-name";

        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
            'key'    => 'xxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        ));


            $baseImageUrl = "http://www.xxxxx.com/banner_mobile.jpg";

            $keyname = "31.jpg";
            try {
            // Upload data.
            $result = $s3->putObject(array(
                 'Bucket'       => $bucket,
                'Key'          => $keyname,
                'Body'   => $baseImageUrl,
                'ContentType'  => 'image/jpg',
                'ACL'          => 'public-read'

            ));
            // Print the URL to the object.
            echo $result['ObjectURL'] . "\n";

            } catch (S3Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            } catch(Exception $ex){
                echo $ex->getMessage()."\n";
            }
```

An empty file (or corrupted file) gets uploaded to s3 bucket. The actual size of image is 37KB, but the uploaded file was of size 40B. What is the reason for this?

Comment: `$baseImageUrl` should be a path to a local file not the `url` to this file

Comment: @mayank: i want the same thing to be done as uploading an image from a web service result image url into the s3 bucket specified location.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you're inserting the url as the body of the file, so you're uploading a image file with text, if you want to upload that file you'll need to have the path or the content of the file